Referring to a previously computed target in tarchetypes::tar_hook_outer()
I would like to refer to a previously computed target as an argument to a hook function called by tarchetypes::tar_hook_outer(). Here is an example _targets.R file that shows the problem.
postprocess <- function(the_target, arg) {
  paste(the_target, arg)
}

list(
  targets::tar_target(Suffix, "--postprocessed"),
  targets::tar_target(A, "A")
) |>
  tarchetypes::tar_hook_outer(
    hook = postprocess(.x, arg = Suffix),
    names = "A"
  )

The result of calling tar_make() is the following:

── Last error message ───────────────────────────────────────────────────
object 'Suffix' not found
── Last error traceback ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
postprocess("A", arg = Suffix)
paste(the_target, arg)
.handleSimpleError(function (condition)  {     state$error <- build_mess...
h(simpleError(msg, call))

I expect successful completion of this simple pipeline and that target A would have the value "A--postprocessed".
How can I successfully refer to the Suffix target as an argument to postprocess()?
Note that this pattern worked in the August 2024 timeframe. I see that tarchetypes::tar_hook_outer_raw() was introduced in tarchetypes 0.10.0 (2024-09-26) which may have broken the previous behavior.
Any help will be much appreciated!

I can reproduce the error with tarchetypes 0.10.0, but it goes away in version 0.11.0. Please upgrade to tarchetypes 0.11.0 and verify you have the correct version installed using packageVersion("tarchetypes"). At the moment, CRAN does not show the Mac binaries for 0.11.0, so you might have to set type = "source" in install.packages().

Awesome, Will! Thanks!

My example works with v. 0.11.0.

tarchetypes v. 0.11.0 fixes this problem, as suggested in the comments.
